# Azure Cognitive Search Demo App - Set number of results per page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have downloaded the Demo App provided by Azure Portal, which implements Azure Cognitive Search. I've been trying to change the number of results per page to a different value, but I could not find any solution. The default number of results per page is 50. There are ways to change it if we created the code from scratch, but I am looking for an easier way to just plug it. As mentioned in the link https://github.com/jj09/azsearch.js we could alter the options using **automagic**, but no such way found to alter the number of results per page.
Would be a great help if anyone could give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the number of results using $top in the url. In the link you've shared, there's this setting:

```
type SuggestionsParametersUpdate = {
        top?: number;
        filter?: string;
        orderby?: string;
        fuzzy?: boolean;
        highlightPreTag?: string;
        highlightPostTag?: string;
        select?: string;
        searchFields?: string;
        minimumCoverage?: string;
        apiVersion?: SearchApiVersion;
        suggesterName?: string;
    };
```

try setting top parameter with value you want.

Comment: Thank you this works. I've been using the keyword `type` in a non-trypscript file, which was giving me the issue. I just changed it to `var`. Thank you